# How can I force the import of an older version of QtQuick?

Tags: qml, qtquick2

I want to test some code with older version of QtQuick, how can I import a specific version?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32013993/6165833) that the import statement is only asking for a minimum version, but that the environment will provide the latest. I don't know how to verify this, nor to check which lib version my program is actually running with.

I am using QtCreator and .pro file.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the exact version of import libraries:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
 import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 as QC2
 MainWindow{
    Button {
        id: oldButton
    }
    QC2.Button {
        id: newButton
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but I still don't know what version I am getting. Using the debug `QML_IMPORT_TRACE` shows me that both imports are using the same path in my Qt installation `...5.9.3/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick.2/qmldir` without any warning, and I have no clue if my imports of 2.0 and 2.9 have included different libs or not. This is working fine for QQuickControls apparently, because the major version is different.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not do that. Maybe it is because Qt runtime does not contains every version of QtQuick . So it just use the latest one. So the minor version number is ignored.